# Understanding Ruby Versioning Conflicts: Unraveling the Net::ProtocRetryError and Net::BufferedIO::BUFSIZE Warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-2.7

Every time i'm  working when i try to launch any gem like mailcatcher, start my server or run the command *rails c* i see this error message and i don't know why it's look like some kind of error version un ruby.

> /home/santiago/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:66: warning: already initialized constant Net::ProtocRetryError
>
> /home/santiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.1/lib/net/protocol.rb:68: warning: previous definition of ProtocRetryError was here
>
> /home/santiago/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:206: warning: already initialized constant Net::BufferedIO::BUFSIZE
>
> /home/santiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.1/lib/net/protocol.rb:214: warning: previous definition of BUFSIZE was here
>
> /home/santiago/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:503: warning: already initialized constant Net::NetPrivate::Socket
>
> /home/santiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.1/lib/net/protocol.rb:541: warning: previous definition of Socket was here

I'm using this ruby version: **ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux]**

Rails version: **Rails 6.0.4.7**.

And I installed ruby with **rvm 1.29.12 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io].**

[image]

I tried to update net-protocol gem, change the ruby version  to another version of 2.7.0 but didn't work.

i want to know why is this happening and solve it to not see these kind of message anymore.

Comment: https://github.com/ruby/net-protocol/issues/10 and https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/44175#issuecomment-1023595691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some (maybe all, I am not sure) of the Net::* classes were moved from the stdlib to gems (they were gemified) around Ruby 3.0.
Since then, for Ruby versions previous to 3.0, gems that depend on the Net::* classes (such as faraday) may be loading the same class twice. Once from the stdlib and once from the gem.

Solution 1 upgrade to ruby 3.X (I can't apply this solution).
Solution 2 explícity add **net-http** to your gemfile, works for not see the message.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the `net-protocol` gem, it's part of the stdlib.

Comment: Not that simple it seems, since the `net-protocol` gem is a secondary dependency of `actionmailer` and `actionmailbox`. It appears the current recommended change is to add `net-http` to the gem file when using ruby < 3.1. This is because `net-smtp`, `net-imap`, and `net-pop` were dropped from stdlib in 3.1. [Change List](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2021/12/25/ruby-3-1-0-released/)

Comment: I think you missed that OP is using ruby 2.7 and Rails 6.0.

Comment: I think this is very dependent on what version of the `mail` gem is being used. The spec for rails 6.0 is simply `"mail", ">= 2.7.1"`, so if this resolves to `2.8.0+` (which is likely given the release date 2 years ago) then these errors will still occur for the same reason, as the inclusion of the `net-*` gems are a dependency of `mail` as of 2.8.0.

Comment: I mean that's great additional info, but different than what you just said. He would want to uninstall the `net-protocol` gem AND pin `mail` to 2.7 no?

Comment: Not different those rails libraries depend on `mail` and `mail` depends on the `net-*` gems. The OP could pin the mail gem or as mentioned add `net-http` to the bundle (which appears to have been successful). Additionally `mail` may not be the only gem that relies on the new gems, the `net-http` suggestion seems to counteract that concern regardless.

Comment: Really no idea how adding `net-http` would change anything but maybe you should put it as an answer and explain it a bit more.